# Abstract class instantiating inner class

Tags: java, static, instance, instantiation, abstract

I have an abstract class with a non-static non abstract inner class that I have to instantiate from a static method. how can this be done?

This is basically what I am trying to do:

```
abstract class Program
{
    private static Window window;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        window = program.new Window();
    }

    abstract void Update();

    class Window
    {
        public Window()
        {
            //some code
        }

        public void someMethod()
        {
            Update();
        }
    }
}
```

I know you cannot instantiate an abstract class, and you can't instantiate the inner class from a static method without an instance of the outer class, so I have no idea what to do.

Comment: You can extend that abstract class and instantiate your inner class using instance of that concrete subclass

Comment: You know the reason behind that, then why should you still want to do it?

Comment: Or use a static inner class. Then you don't need an instance of the outer class to instantiate it on.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is just create one class which extends your abstract  class and in that class you can instantiate your inner class like following:

```
public class TestProgram extends Program
 {

  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    Program program = new TestProgram();
    Window window = program.new Window();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer seems to be create an implementation of Program that you can use to instantiate Window objects from.

More generally, I think your paradox is your answer. You're trying to design something that won't work within the language constraints and you'll have to give up the abstract nature of Program or make Window a class you can create outside of a Program.

Comment: Is it possible to just create an instance of a possible subclass of Program?

Comment: You can create an instance of any class as long as that class is not abstract and you have visibility to a constructor of that class. 

I might be reading into your words too literally, but you can't create instances of a possible subclass that may or may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have your main method inside of an `abstract class`?

The bigger problem here is the design. What is the point of having that Window class an inner class? If you want to instantiate that object from within the abstract class, just make Window it's own top level class.

It doesnt appear to access anything from its containing class, so why have it be an inner class?

Comment: basically I am trying to make a game loop template, where all you have to do is extend the Program class and implement the methods and you will have an easy game loop